# TypeError: counters.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

I want to increment value with js DOM, but when i try to run my code then it shows me an error like this:

```
   5 | const Counter = () => {
   6 |   useEffect(() => {
   7 |     const counters = document.querySelector(".counter");
>  8 |     counters.forEach((counter) => {
   9 |       counter.innerText = "0";
  10 |       const updateCounter = () => {
  11 |         const target = +counter.getAttribute("data-target");
```

```
TypeError: counter.forEach is not a function.
```

I don't know why this shows me error like this.

I have tried follow code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faLaptop } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

const Counter = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const counters = document.querySelector(".counter");
    counters.forEach((counter) => {
      counter.innerText = "0";
      const updateCounter = () => {
        const target = +counter.getAttribute("data-target");
        const c = +counter.innerText;
        const increment = target / 200;

        if (c < target) {
          counter.innerText = `${Math.ceil(c + increment)}`;
          setTimeout(updateCounter, 1);
        } else {
          counter.innerText = target;
        }
      };
      updateCounter();
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="cus_counter">
      <div className="counter-container">
        <i>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faLaptop} />
        </i>
        <div className="counter" data-target="12000"></div>
        <span>Twitter Followers</span>
      </div>

      <div className="counter-container">
        <i>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faLaptop} />
        </i>
        <div className="counter" data-target="5000"></div>
        <span>Twitter Followers</span>
      </div>

      <div className="counter-container">
        <i>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faLaptop} />
        </i>
        <div className="counter" data-target="1000"></div>
        <span>Twitter Followers</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Counter;
```

If i don't use useEffect,  it still shows the error.

Any suggestion please.

Comment: Do you mean `querySelectorAll`? Also, why are you doing it using DOM API instead of using state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `querySelector` method returns the first element that matches a specified CSS selector(s) in the document. The method `forEach` is only available on arrays. You should use `querySelectorAll` in this case.

By the way, when using React it would be better to use the `useRef` hook to refer to your elements. If you want to read more: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

Answer (score 0):

The Document method `querySelector()` returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned.
Since array is not returned, can not use `forEach`

Comment: `querySelectorAll` doesn't return an array. It returns a `NodeList` which has a `forEach` method.

Answer (score 0):

`querySelector` only selects one element. You should use `querySelectorAll` to select all the elements with the given class.